# C++ code migration. Method implementation keeps saying missing type

Tags: c++, oop, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to migrate some code written in an older version of Visual Studio (VS 2006) to the 2015 version, and I stumbled upon an error in multiple files.

```
#ifndef C_I3E_TYPE_ARRAY_H_
#define C_I3E_TYPE_ARRAY_H_

#include "C_I3E_Type.h"

class C_I3E_Type_Array:public C_I3E_Type   {
protected:
virtual void Read(FILE *p_Stream);
unsigned int m_High_Bound;}
```

It's about the *Read* method.

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "C_I3E_Type_Array.h"
#include "C_I3E_File.h"
#include "C_I3E_Module.h"
C_I3E_Type_Array::Read(FILE *p_Stream){

unsigned int linked_type_index;

//Get the Type Index
linked_type_index = Read_Numeric_Format(p_Stream);
m_Linked_Type = m_Parent->Get_Type_ByIndex(linked_type_index);

//Get the High Bound value of the array
m_High_Bound = Read_Numeric_Format(p_Stream);}
```

It keeps sending me this error :

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State 
>   Error C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
>   support default-int   MaskGen
>   d:\temp\bll\maskgen_whole_wo_dll\maskgen_all_classes_enabled\maskgen\classes\c_i3e\C_I3E_Type_Array.h 9

Comment: You need to specify the return type `void`, like `void C_I3E_Type_Array::Read(FILE *p_Stream){ ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is quite descriptive, consider the line bellow:

```
C_I3E_Type_Array::Read(FILE *p_Stream) {
```

In the header file, there's a `void` there. So it should be:

```
void C_I3E_Type_Array::Read(FILE *p_Stream) {
```

Comment: Thank you very much! :) I hope it works. Besides that error, I've got a few more next in line.

Answer (score 0):

`#include "C_I3E_File.h"` in the header. Add `void` before `Read()`'s definition.